# Creating a CvCapture from a sequence of images

Tags: c++, c, opencv

The function `cvCaptureFromAVI` allocates and initializes a `CvCapture` structure in order to read a video stream from the specified file. The function `cvCaptureFromCAM` works in a similar way, but the source of the video is a webcam. Once the `CvCapture` structure has been allocated and initialized properly, the reading of each frame is performed using the function `cvQueryFrame`.

Since I have a sequence of frames as images saved on disk, I would allocate a `CvCapture` structure for reading an image stream from the specified file list. How should I initialize the `CvCapture` structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned OpenCV's **C** API, the magic is done by `cvCreateVideoWriter()`.

[Here's a demo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5782246/176769) using Python.