# How to create video using avcodec from jpeg images of type OpenCV::Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv, video, ffmpeg, libavcodec

I have colored jpeg images of `OpenCV::Mat` type and I create from them video using `avcodec`. The video that I get is upside-down, black & white and each row of each frame is shifted and I got diagonal line. What could be the reason for such output?
Follow [this](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/ZNQeoPw8YFBa-iFpzuYi4dMTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink) link to watch the video I get using avcodec.
I'm using `acpicture_fill` function to create `avFrame` from `cv::Mat` frame!

P.S.
Each cv::Mat cvFrame has  width=810, height=610, step=2432
I noticed that avFrame (that is filled by acpicture_fill) has `linesize[0]=2430`
I tried manually setting `avFrame->linesizep0]=2432` and not 2430 but it still didn't helped.

**======== CODE =========================================================**

```
AVCodec *encoder = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
AVStream *outStream = avformat_new_stream(outContainer, encoder);
avcodec_get_context_defaults3(outStream->codec, encoder);

outStream->codec->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
outStream->codec->width = 810;
outStream->codec->height = 610;
//...

SwsContext *swsCtx = sws_getContext(outStream->codec->width, outStream->codec->height, PIX_FMT_RGB24,
                                    outStream->codec->width, outStream->codec->height,  outStream->codec->pix_fmt, SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL);

for (uint i=0; i < frameNums; i++)
{
    // get frame at location I using OpenCV
    cv::Mat cvFrame;
    myReader.getFrame(cvFrame, i); 
    cv::Size frameSize = cvFrame.size();    
    //Each cv::Mat cvFrame has  width=810, height=610, step=2432


1.  // create AVPicture from cv::Mat frame
2.  avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)avFrame, cvFrame.data, PIX_FMT_RGB24, outStream->codec->width, outStream->codec->height);
3avFrame->width = frameSize.width;
4.  avFrame->height = frameSize.height;

    // rescale to outStream format
    sws_scale(swsCtx, avFrame->data, avFrame->linesize, 0, outStream->codec->height, avFrameRescaledFrame->data, avFrameRescaledFrame ->linesize);
encoderRescaledFrame->pts=i;
avFrameRescaledFrame->width = frameSize.width;
    avFrameRescaledFrame->height = frameSize.height;

av_init_packet(&avEncodedPacket);
    avEncodedPacket.data = NULL;
    avEncodedPacket.size = 0;

    // encode rescaled frame
    if(avcodec_encode_video2(outStream->codec, &avEncodedPacket, avFrameRescaledFrame, &got_frame) < 0) exit(1);
    if(got_frame)
    {
        if (avEncodedPacket.pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE)
            avEncodedPacket.pts =  av_rescale_q(avEncodedPacket.pts, outStream->codec->time_base, outStream->time_base);
        if (avEncodedPacket.dts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE)
            avEncodedPacket.dts = av_rescale_q(avEncodedPacket.dts, outStream->codec->time_base, outStream->time_base);

        // outContainer is "mp4"
        av_write_frame(outContainer, & avEncodedPacket);

        av_free_packet(&encodedPacket);
    }
}
```

**UPDATED**

As @Alex suggested I changed the lines 1-4 with the code below

```
int width = frameSize.width, height = frameSize.height; 
avpicture_alloc((AVPicture*)avFrame, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, outStream->codec->width, outStream->codec->height);
for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
{
     memcpy(&(avFrame->data[0][h*avFrame->linesize[0]]), &(cvFrame.data[h*cvFrame.step]), width*3);
}
```

The video ([here](https://picasaweb.google.com/103161760482140400348/2December201202#5817342583034854274)) I get now is almost perfect. It's NOT upside-down, NOT black & white, BUT it seems that one of the RGB components is missing. Every brown/red colors became blue (in original images it should be vice-verse).
What could be the problem? Could rescaling(`sws_scale`) to `AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P` format causes this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in a nutshell: `avpicture_fill()` expects no padding between rows, ie the stride (step) to be equal to `width*sizeof(pixel)`, ie 810*3 = 2430.  The actual stride of the data in cv::Mat step as you say is 2432 which is different, so just passing the data directly won't work.  There is no way to tell `avpicture_fill()` to use a different stride for the input data; it is not part of the API (you might say it should be :)

There are two possible solutions:

Create an array in which the input data is contiguous, no padding between rows.  You'd have to memcopy each row from the cv::Mat into that array.  Then pass it to `avpicture_fill()`.

```
int width, height; // get from mat
uint8_t* buf = malloc(width * height * 3); // 3 bytes per pixel
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    memcpy( &( buf[ i*width*3 ] ), &( mat->data[ i*mat->step ] ), width*3 );
}
avpicture_fill(..., buf, ...)
```

Btw, to flip the video vertically, you can do this to copy the last row to the first and so forth:

```
...
    memcpy( &( buf[ i*width*3 ] ), &( mat->data[ (height - i - 1)*mat->step ] ), width*3 );
...
```

Or, fill in the AVPicture yourself:

```
AVPicture* pic = malloc(sizeof(AVPicture));
avpicture_alloc(pic, PIX_FMT_BGR24, width, height);
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    memcpy( &( pic->data[0][ i*pic->linesize[0] ] ),  &( mat->data[ i*mat->step ] ), width*3);
}
```

There is no need to allocate pic->data[0] or set pic->linesize[0], avpicture_alloc() should do that.  There is also no need to fill in data[1] or data[2], those should be null.

**EDIT:** Removed old code which showed copying R, G, B to separate planes.  PIX_FMT_BGR24 is not a planar format.

I'm not familiar enough with OpenCV C++ API to figure out how to get the width and height (it's not mat->width, obviously) but I think you know what I mean.

P.S. Btw, your video is not *actually* black and white.  It's just that each successive row is offset by two bytes, so the colors are rotated: red becomes green, green becomes blue, and so forth.  The result is grayscale-ish, but if you look closely the individual rows are colored.

Comment: I understand that I need to allocate buffer for `pic->data[0]` and for `pic->data[1]` and `pic->data[2]` equally to how much? and `pic->linesize[0]` is also 0, should I put there 2430?

Comment: I'm actually not quite sure how avpicture_fill() fills a picture when the format is BGR24.  Please see the edit above.

Comment: You don't need to allocate pic->data[0] or set linesize, avpicture_alloc() should do that.  This is all for the second method anyway.  Please try the first method first (copy data to buf without padding and call avpicture_fill).

Comment: it's not BGR24, but RGB24. My mistake. I updated my post. I'll try the first method

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it almost succeeded. The problem is that every brown/red colors became blue (in original images it should be vice-verse). Do you have any ideas? I update my post and attached link to the video I get(https://picasaweb.google.com/103161760482140400348/2December201202#5817342583034854274)

Comment: @theateist: Good, getting close :)  If you are calling avpicture_fill and sws_getContext with RGB format, call both with BGR instead (keeping everything else the same).  If you are calling with BGR, try RGB.  That will swap the red and blue.

Comment: It helped! I changed both `avpicture_alloc` and `sws_getContext` to PIX_FMT_BGR24 and it helped, but why? Does this mean that the jpeg image was coded with BGR and not RGB? The second question is where did you read that `avpicture_fill` expects no padding between rows?

Comment: @theateist: jpeg is usually stored as YCbCr, but it does seem that when you create a cv::Mat from a jpeg the result is BGR.  For avpicture_fill, [this doc](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__picture.html) says "always assume a linesize alignment of 1" which I interpreted as no padding.  Also, there is no way to specify any particular linesize/padding when passing data to avpicture_fill, so no padding would be the default assumption.  Please remember to accept my answer and upvote it :) Thanks!

Comment: If I could I would give you a medal for your explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [OpenCV's features](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5782246/176769) to create the video for you? It's much more easier since your data is already store in a `cv::Mat`.

If you would like to keep your approach, you could simply [rotate the `cv::Mat`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7825243/176769).

Comment: I cannot use OpenCV's to create video. I have to use avcodec for this. I tried to use rotate, but it didn't fixed it. I still get Black&White video and diagonal lines. I guess it something with stride

Answer (score 0):

About the color problem in the UPDATE of the original post. Is that caused by,

OpenCV Mat is (BGR) -> FFmpeg AVFrame is (RGB) ?

If so, try,

```
cvtColor( cvFrame , cvFrame , CV_BGR2RGB ) ;
```

before line 1.