# Why can't I preview my TIFF images with Jupyter ? And why am I failing to make a video out of those TIFF images?

Tags: python, image, tiff, utf

I have a file with a lot of .tif images.

*Part 1. Preview of TIFF images*

When I try to opreview them by clicking on them in the jupyter folder (which look like this one [the Jupyter folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfAMd.png)), I get the following message :

> Error ! D:...\image.tif is not UTF-8 encoded

On the opposite, if I click on a png in the Jupyter folder, Jupyter does display an image.

How could I fix my images, knowing that I have more than 1000 of them in my folder ?

Nonetheless, if I write :

```
sph = cv2.imread('A1.tif',-1)
plt.imshow(sph)
plt.show()
```

I do get the image : [image of 'A1.tif'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuWlt.png).

Now I also checked :

```
import chardet
chardet.detect('A1.det')
--> {'confidence': 1.0, 'encoding': 'ascii', 'language': ''}  # result
```

So apparently I it is encoded in ascii. Is it the same as utf-8 or should I convert them ?

**Edit : Answer :** In one of the comments, @FabienP answers that "According the official documentation, Jupyter lab does not support TIFF format for image preview (as of now)", which answers this question.

*Part 2  : writing a video out of TIFF images*

I have another question and I don't know if both questions are connected.

I want to make a video out of them.

```
import cv2
import os
image_folder = 'A549_A1'
video_name = 'video.avi'

images = [img for img in os.listdir(image_folder) if img.endswith(".tif")]
frame = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, images[0]))
height, width, layers = frame.shape

video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name, 0, 1, (width,height))

for image in images:
     video.write(cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, image)))

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
```

But instead of getting the expected video, I get a strange one with many images at one step :  [caption of the video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqikD.jpg). You can compare it to the image above to check that it's not normal.

How can I fix that ?

Comment: This is *very* confused. UTF-8 is a text encoding; it makes absolutely no sense to require it for data which isn't text at all.

Comment: If you show your code, as required by the **Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example**, you will be more likely to get an answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @tripleee Do you mean my question is confused or the error message is confused ?

Comment: Your images are fine - I presume you can see them in the normal Windows File Explorer (*"My Computer"* thing)? They do not need to be UTF-8. Nor ASCII. Nor decoded. Nor encoded. Maybe take a step back and say what you are trying to achieve here...

Comment: According the official documentation, Jupyter lab [does not support TIFF](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/file_formats.html#images) format for image preview (as of now).

Comment: If, as suggested, TIFFs are not supported, you could use **ImageMagick** to make PNG versions of all your TIFF files using this command in **Command Prompt** `magick mogrify -format PNG *.tif` Though, if you actually want to read them with OpenCV, this is not necessary because it understands TIFFs anyway.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thx for your answers. What you're saying regarding cv2 is half right, since there is an issue with cv2.VideoWriter . Besides that, is there a possibility to write a command that would convert all those TIFF files to PNG ? Because that it's quite long to convert all of them one by one.

Comment: Personally, I would be looking at using `ffmpeg`... https://stackoverflow.com/a/24966617/2836621

Comment: The **ImageMagick** command I suggested will make PNG versions of all your TIFFs with the one, single command.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Great I will have a look at ffmpeg. Regarding ImageMagick, where do I enter the path in the command ?

Comment: The command assumes you have used `CD` to change directory to the one containing your images.

Comment: The CV2 documentation indicates that the `cv2.VideoWriter` will run `ffmpeg` (or Linux and possibly Windows) behind the scenes anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting the bytes in an image from ASCII to UTF-8 makes only slightly more sense than converting them from Fahrenheit to Celsius, or transposing them to B♭ major. If you can find a way to do it technically, all it will do is wreck the image. Indeed, this is completely a red herring, and has absolutely nothing to do with your video conversion problem.

Text encodings like ASCII and UTF-8 describe how characters map between code points or glyphs and computer representations. There is no text in an image file; it is just a bunch of pixels. Maybe see also the seminal 2003 blog post [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Moreover, because UTF-8 is ASCII compatible, every ASCII file is already trivially a UTF-8 file. There is no transformation you can apply to make it "more UTF-8".

Binary formats, on the other hand, typically have an internal structure which is quite different. For just an image, a trivial format might simply encode each black pixel as a 1 bit and each white pixel as a 0 bit. (In fact, the very first version of [TIFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF) did exactly this, with a few additional frills.) You can add a constant to each byte, for example, but this will simply transform it into a jumble which no longer contains a valid picture. Examine what happens if you add one to a number like 63 which has a lot of 1 bits in the lower half in its binary representation:

```
 63    0011 1111      ..XX XXXX  <- sequence of black pixels
+ 1  + 0000 0001      .... ...X
---- -----------     ----------
 64    0100 0000      .X.. ....  <- one black pixel, lots of white
```

Modern binary formats are quite a bit more complex, and often contain header sequences which indicate how many bytes of data follow or where to look for a particular feature to populate a data structure in memory. Replacing these values with other values will almost certainly create a stream which is simply corrupted unless you know exactly what you are doing.

---

Comparing against https://stackoverflow.com/a/34555939/874188 and googling for a bit suggests that passing `0` as the `fourcc` parameter might be the source of your problems.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31401095/874188 suggests `cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(list("MJPG"))`, though another answer on the same question alleges that it used to work poorly at one point, and has many other options you could try.